# Find the joint density of $\min(X,Y)$ and $X-Y$ using bivariate transform

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent exponential random variable, where $X\sim \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x}$ and $Y\sim \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 y}$. How would one use bivariate transform to find the joint density of $S: =\min\left(X,Y\right)$ and $T:= X-Y$?

If we consider the mapping $g:\left(X,Y\right) \to \left(S ,T\right)$, then on $A_1 = \{(x,y): x > y\}$ and $A_2 = \{(x,y): y > x\}$, we can find inverse of $g$. However, $g$ maps $A_1$ to the first quadrant of $(s,t)$ plane, and maps $A_2$ to the fourth quadrant of $(s,t)$. How should I proceed? My textbook only discusses when $g$ maps $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ onto the same $B$. For your reference, here is the excerpt

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can follow the usual routine procedure of change of variables.

Due to independence, joint density of $(X,Y)$ is given by $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\lambda_1\lambda_2 e^{-(\lambda_1x+\lambda_2y)}\mathbf1_{x>0,y>0}\qquad,\,\lambda_1,\lambda_2>0$$

We transform $(X,Y)\to(S,T)$ where $S=\min(X,Y)$ and $T=X-Y$.

Consider the two cases $x>y$ and $x\leqslant y$ separately. Being a linear transformation, for each of the cases, absolute value of the Jacobian ($J_i$) of transformation turns out to be unity.

Thus we obtain the joint density of $(S,T)$, given by

\begin{align}
f_{S,T}(s,t)&=f_{X,Y}(s,s-t)\left|J_1\right|\mathbf1_{t<0,s>0}+f_{X,Y}(s+t,s)\left|J_2\right|\mathbf1_{t>0,s>0}
\\\\&=\lambda_1\lambda_2e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)s}e^{\lambda_2t}\mathbf1_{t<0,s>0}+\lambda_1\lambda_2e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)s}e^{-\lambda_1t}\mathbf1_{t>0,s>0}
\\\\&=\lambda_1\lambda_2e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)s}\mathbf1_{s>0}\left(e^{\lambda_2t}\mathbf1_{t<0}+e^{-\lambda_1t}\mathbf1_{t>0}\right)
\\\\&=(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)s}\mathbf1_{s>0}\,\frac{\lambda_1\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\left(e^{\lambda_2t}\mathbf1_{t<0}+e^{-\lambda_1t}\mathbf1_{t>0}\right)
\\\\&=f_{S}(s)f_{T}(t)
\end{align}

This shows the independence of $S$ and $T$, where $S$ in particular has an Exponential distribution with rate $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$. Had $\lambda_1$ been equal to $\lambda_2$ (i.e. if $X$ and $Y$ were i.i.d), then $T$ would have had a Laplace distribution.

It is interesting to note that this problem is related to a [certain characterization](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2238249) of the Exponential distribution, namely the independence of $\min(X,Y)$ and $X-Y$ for two absolutely continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ iff $X$ and $Y$ are independent Exponential random variables with the same location parameter.

Comment: So the "onto" assumption doesn't matter?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the first indicator function be $1\{ s > 0, s-t > 0\}$?

Comment: @3x89g2 Well I used the general formula right at the end of the excerpt from your book.

Comment: So here $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_ x} e^{-\lambda_2} 1\{x>0\} 1\{y>0\}$. If we let $x=s, y = s-t$, don't we get $1\left\{ s>0, s-t > 0\right\}$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @3x89g2 The first case is $x<y\implies s=x>0, t=x-y<0$. You missed the constraint $x<y$ in that last comment.

Comment: Right, I get that we are splitting the whole $(x,y)$-plane into $x<y$ and $y>x$. But my confusion was, that doesn't seem to be reflected in the general formula in the book...

Comment: That transformation formula is what we use when the map is not one-to-one, as in this case. Here we decompose the sample space of $(X,Y)$ into two sets such that the transformation is one-to-one separately on these sets. We have the two inverse solutions $(x,y)=(s,s-t)$ and $(x,y)=(s+t,s)$ for the two cases $x<y$ and $x>y$ respectively. |Jacobian| in each case is $1$. So the first equality in this answer after $f_{S,T}()$ basically reflects that formula.

Comment: @3x89g2 The general formula has no consideration of $x<y$ or $x>y$. We have these cases here to find the inverse solutions.

Comment: I think your approach is right (in fact I did the same thing). I am just trying to fit this solution to the recipe in the book. So in book's language, we have $A_1 = \{x<y\}$, $A_2 = \{x > y\}$, and $A_0 \{ x=y\}$ which we ignore, right? The transform from $(x,y)$ to $(s,t)$ is one-to-one and onto, but to _different regions_. The book require that they are to the same region $B$, but here we obviously need something like $B_1, B_2$ corresponding to $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Comment: I'm just wondering maybe there is a more general version.

Comment: I think I know what’s going on. I consulted a different book and that book doesn’t even mention “onto’...Maybe the author here doesn’t mean “onto” as “subjective”...

Comment: @3x89g2 Actually the transformation is not two-to-one (in the usual sense) now that I see. The general formula does not really apply. The way I have written the joint density is just a shorthand for breaking up the two cases.